# MatLab installation from .iso problem

Tags: installation, java, iso, matlab

I tried installing MatLab on Ubuntu 12.04 from an .iso, unsuccessfully. The .iso file is mounted, but when I go to the mounted folder and type `./install` , I get this error message:

```
Error: Cannot locate Java Runtime Environment (JRE).
The directory /mnt/iso/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre does not exist.
```

That seems pretty normal, since the directory glnx86 doesn't exist, but instead, in the install script, it seems like this should be exchanged with glnxa64, which does exist. I tried to modify the script in the install file and deleted the glnx86 values, retried to run the script, but then I get another error message:

```
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
/tmp/mathworks_11559/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: 1: /tmp/mathworks_11559/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Finished
```

Can someone help me out of this, please?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB

Comment: I checked that, but I think that it won't help. Apparently this is a fix for the 64 bit version, but I'm running a 32 bit version. Thus, trying to get the "ia32-libs" package won't work. But I think I see the problem here: I have a version of Matlab made to run in only 64 Ubuntu (2012b, 2012a seems to be the last version for 32 bit). Should I mark this solved?

Comment: If you got it solved then feel free to close it. But please add additional information regarding how you came to that conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last version of MatLab supported by a 32-bit Linux OS is the 2012a. All versions coming after this one can only be installed on a 64-bit Linux OS. I upgraded my OS to Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, and installed the 2013a version of MatLab following the instructions that already exist in the forum. By the way, it looks that the fix for "ia32-libs" (mentioned as comment on my previous question) is only needed for older versions of MatLab, in my case there was no need to get the package.